# canvasjs, show one value in chart but another in X axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvasjs

im using CanvasJs to show some charts. 
And when I move the mouse over the point it shows the wrong date
In the picture Im over 12-jun but it says 11-jun.. happens the same in every point.

The value "32" is OK, the date is not ok..

but if i show the series in separated charts the data is ok.

[image: Chart]

script:

```
$.getJSON("dataNro7.php", function (result) {


            var dps1 = [], dps2 = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {



            switch(result[i].palabra) {

            case 'pa': dps1.push({ x:  new Date (result[i].label), y: result[i].y });
                break;
            case 'ma': dps2.push({ x:  new Date(result[i].label), y: result[i].y });
                break;
            }
        }


                var revenueBarChart = new CanvasJS.Chart("Historiales2y3", {
                    animationEnabled: false,
                    backgroundColor: "transparent",
                    theme: "theme2",
                    axisX:{
                            interval: 2,
                            valueFormatString: "DD-MMM" ,
                            gridThickness: 0,
                            labelFontSize: 12,
                            labelMaxWidth: 100,
                            labelAngle: 0,
                            culture: "es",
                            labelFontStyle: "normal",
                            labelFontWeight: "normal",
                            labelFontFamily: "Lucida Sans Unicode"

                        },
                    axisY2:{

                            labelFontSize: 12,
                            interlacedColor: "rgba(1,77,101,.05)",
                            gridColor: "rgba(1,77,101,.1)"

                        },


                    data: [   { type: "splineArea",
                                showInLegend: true,
                                name: "PA",
                                color: "rgba(12,143,221,.8)",
                                axisYType: "secondary",
                                 dataPoints: dps1 },

                            { type: "splineArea",
                                showInLegend: true,
                                name: "MA",
                                color: "rgba(192,143,121,.8)",
                                axisYType: "secondary",
                                 dataPoints: dps2 } ]

                });


                revenueBarChart.render();
            });
```

JSON:

```
[{"palabra":"pa","y":22,"label":"2017-05-28"},
 {"palabra":"ma","y":10,"label":"2017-05-28"},
 {"palabra":"pa","y":8,"label":"2017-05-29"},
 {"palabra":"ma","y":30,"label":"2017-05-29"},
 {"palabra":"pa","y":0,"label":"2017-05-30"},
 {"palabra":"ma","y":0,"label":"2017-05-30"},
 {"palabra":"pa","y":12,"label":"2017-05-31"},
 {"palabra":"ma","y":16,"label":"2017-05-31"},                    
 {"palabra":"pa","y":7,"label":"2017-06-01"},
 {"palabra":"ma","y":36,"label":"2017-06-01"},
 {"palabra":"pa","y":12,"label":"2017-06-02"},
 {"palabra":"ma","y":33,"label":"2017-06-02"},
 {"palabra":"pa","y":0,"label":"2017-06-03"},
 {"palabra":"ma","y":14,"label":"2017-06-03"},{"palabra":"pa","y":5,"label":"2017-06-04"},{"palabra":"ma","y":30,"label":"2017-06-04"},{"palabra":"pa","y":19,"label":"2017-06-05"},{"palabra":"ma","y":25,"label":"2017-06-05"},{"palabra":"pa","y":11,"label":"2017-06-06"},{"palabra":"ma","y":35,"label":"2017-06-06"},{"palabra":"pa","y":24,"label":"2017-06-07"},{"palabra":"ma","y":34,"label":"2017-06-07"},{"palabra":"pa","y":24,"label":"2017-06-08"},{"palabra":"ma","y":59,"label":"2017-06-08"},{"palabra":"pa","y":0,"label":"2017-06-09"},{"palabra":"ma","y":39,"label":"2017-06-09"},{"palabra":"pa","y":14,"label":"2017-06-10"},{"palabra":"ma","y":22,"label":"2017-06-10"},{"palabra":"pa","y":13,"label":"2017-06-11"},{"palabra":"ma","y":6,"label":"2017-06-11"},{"palabra":"pa","y":18,"label":"2017-06-12"},{"palabra":"ma","y":32,"label":"2017-06-12"},{"palabra":"pa","y":17,"label":"2017-06-13"},{"palabra":"ma","y":49,"label":"2017-06-13"},{"palabra":"pa","y":15,"label":"2017-06-14"},{"palabra":"ma","y":12,"label":"2017-06-14"}]
```

Comment: You should also provide your JSON. Date-time value may change depending on the data type provided in JavaScript Date constructor.

Comment: @Sanjoy Hi, I add the json to the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As documented in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse),

> Given a date string of “March 7, 2014”, parse() assumes a local time
>   zone, but given an ISO format such as “2014-03-07” it will assume a
>   time zone of UTC (ES5 and ECMAScript 2015). Therefore Date objects
>   produced using those strings may represent different moments in time
>   depending on the version of ECMAScript supported unless the system is
>   set with a local time zone of UTC. This means that two date strings
>   that appear equivalent may result in two different values depending on
>   the format of the string that is being converted.

Please check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15517024/how-to-assume-local-time-zone-when-parsing-iso-8601-date-string) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I make it work adding this before the push into the DSP1 and DSP2 array:

```
var current = new Date(result[i].label); 
                var followingDay = new Date(current.getTime() + 12400000); 
                followingDay.toLocaleDateString();
```

Im sure this is not super accurate..but works for now..